# How to convert a time of any country to a specific timezone's time?

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose my time in India is 9:30AM, so i want to convert this time to some other timezone of a different country.

[Click here to see the image preview for this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weVhn.png)

So, i hve this timeslots of 45 mins each of Asia/Calcuuta, and as you see someone has booked the first 2 time slots.

So, now as i as another user from Asia/Karachi try to book the time slot, first it overrides and interchanges the Asia/Calcutta time to Asia/Karachi, but the issue is that those 2 booked slots are show here as Avialable. I want that anyone from any timezone see the booked slots as well.

[Click here to see the image preview for this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdFOF.png)

```
  for(var i=0;i<slotsArray.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<this.bookedTimingsOfUser.length;j++)
    {
    var getStartValInSlice = (this.bookedTimingsOfUser[j][0].userstartTime).slice(0, -3);
 
    if((momenttm(date+ " " + slotsArray[i].timeSlotStart).tz(timezone)).tz(this.bookedTimingsOfUser[j][0].userBookedTimezone).format('LT')  == momenttm(date+ " " + getStartValInSlice).tz(this.bookedTimingsOfUser[j][0].userBookedTimezone).format('LT') &&  moment(getDate.value).format('LL')  == this.bookedTimingsOfUser[j][0].userbookedDate)     

      slotsArray[i].timeSlotStart = "Booked";
     
    }
  }
}
```

**How can i achive this using JS or any other time conversion npm packages like moments.js ???**

Comment: what you can do is convert the booked time to the selected timezone and show that it is booked.

Comment: That is the things, which i am uable to do. Let me share my code here as well.

Comment: I have added the code in the question.

Comment: I think the if condition is wrong as it is unable to change the timezone to the already userBookedTimezone.

Comment: This isn't working because the time is different in different timezones.

Comment: How to fix it? Can you help ?

Comment: Let's see what can be done. You can connect with me via LinkedIn if you have one. I have the link in my profile

Comment: Sent connect request to you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass timezone property to `toLocaleString` method to convert this time to different timezone

```js
const timezoneSelect = document.querySelector('#timezones'),
  displayZone = document.querySelector('strong');

timezoneSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    timeZone: this.value
  });
  displayZone.innerText = date;
})
```

```html
<select name="timezones" id="timezones">
  <option value="Asia/Kolkata">Asia/Kolkata</option>
  <option value="Asia/Karachi">Asia/Karachi</option>
</select>

<p>Current Time: <strong>HH:MM:SS</strong></p>
```

Comment: I got your idea, but i want something different. I am trying to change and switch between time on a button click. Like if i already have a time of Asia/Calcutta "09:00" or any anything, and then i select from a dropdown the timezone of Asia/Karachi. I want the time of Asia/Calcutta to change to Asia/Karachi.

Comment: you should have mentioned that

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to mention. Can you help ?